# Footer doesn't stay down

Tags: html

guys.
Im trying to put a footer at the bottom of the screen and I succeed to do so, but thing is - if the page is scroll-able, once I scroll up, the footer "goes" with me. or let's say I open developer tools debugging , the footer "goes" on top of it instead of staying down. 
I would like the footer to stay at the bottom the whole time. even if the page becomes smaller, I would like not to see it unless I'm at the bottom of the page (scroll wise).
How can I implement that?

Thanks!

Comment: put your code here

Comment: without seeing your code I'm going to take a guess and say you probably haven't cleared your floats. Try clear:both; on footer and see if it works. If it doesn't we can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Wild shot, min-height 100% on html? https://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

Comment: <md-content flex layout="column">
            <md-content layout="column" layout-padding>

                <div ng-view></div>
            </md-content>
            <div flex></div>

            <footer class="copyright">Copyright © 2017 Matrix-Ifs. All rights reserved.</footer>

        </md-content>

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can try the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```